# Change Skype Shortcut

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

does anyone know how to change a shortcut for Skype?

Ctrl+Alt+Shift+3    Open the main window and put focus in the search box.

I only found a regkey to disable shortcuts

Comment: This article might help: [What are hotkeys and how do I use them? - Skype support](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12025/what-are-hotkeys-and-how-do-i-use-them)